# cakephp prevent duplication

Tags: mysql, cakephp, duplicates

I have a table students with ID field which is primary key but not auto numbered
while inserting new record I have to call getNextID() function to get next id to be inserted

```
function getNextID(){
   /*I am type code inside function now not copied from actual code but consider it will return max_1*/
   $max_id = $this->Student->find('list',array(
          'fields'=>array('id'),
          'order'=>array('id desc'),
          'limit'=>1
          ));
   $next_id = $max_id + 1;
}
```

the problem I am facing is
when multiple users call this function at the same time, both will get same $next_id and it will be duplicated
i want to know how can I prevent duplication
note: I am not able to make it auto number

Comment: actually that's why the auto increment is there...:(

Answer (score 2):

> I have a table students with ID field which is primary key but not
>   auto numbered

Why? This doesn't make much sense at all.

Use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). The [probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) of generating a duplicate is more than sufficient.

```
$id = String::uuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my issue by defining a static variable `$locked` as

```
private static $locked;
```

and made a little changes in egtNextID() function as

```
function getNextID(){
    self::$locked = true;
    $max_id = $this->Student->find('list',array(
      'fields'=>array('id'),
      'order'=>array('id desc'),
      'limit'=>1
      ));
    $next_id = $max_id + 1;
    self::$locked = false;
    return $next_id;
}
```

and added few lines before calling getNextID() as

```
 while(self::$locked != false){
     sleep(1);
 }
```

this resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned function to get unique id:-

```
public function createId( $intOnly = true ) {
    $fixed = 1390000000;
    $t = explode( " ", microtime() );
    $uid = $t[1] - $fixed;
    return ( $intOnly ) ? $uid : uniqid();
}
```

default will be integer and if you pass parameter `false` it will give string.

it will always return unique ids.